# How to properly test for valid characters in pattern, possibly using character arrays or some other method(regex)

Tags: python, regex, arrays, char, character-arrays

I have a problem that I can't seem to figure out in Python.  I have a pattern that need to match any of the characters in a character array.  If it doesn't, then there is a problem.  So here are my examples:

pattern = "0000 006e 0022 0002 0156 00ac 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 05e0 0156 0055 0016 0e41"

allowedCharacters = "123456789abcdef"

So my goal is to see if the pattern conforms to the allowed characters.  In C# I did the following, but I can't figure out how to get this done in Python.

Here is my current code.

```
        # Test that there are only valid characters in the pattern.
        charPattern = list(pattern)
        expression = list("01234567890abcdef")

        for currentChar in pattern:
            if len(charPattern) - pattern[-1::-1].index("0123456789abcdef") - 1:
                self.assertTrue(False, logger.failed("The invalid character: " + currentChar + " was found in the IRCode pattern for: " + ircode))`enter code here`
```

Any ideas/suggestions/code examples are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^[0123456789abcdef\s]+$')
str = "0000 006e 0022 0002 0156 00ac 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 05e0 0156 0055 0016 0e41"

if(p.match(str)):
  print("passed")
else:
  list = re.findall('([^0123456789abcdef\s])+', str)
  print(list)
```

It will search in the string for the `0123456789abcdef\s` occurrences. If some character is not in this pattern, then it won't pass

**EDIT:**

Increased the code in case it won't pass, will print all the occurrences which are **invalid**

Comment: I appreciate the response.  Your example works great!  However, if there is an invalid character in the pattern(str) that doesn't match the expression, how can I know what that character is?

Comment: So one other question.  How could I use this same code or new regex code to look for spaces, tabs, carriage returns, and line feeds?  We could use the same example of p = re.compile(r'^[0123456789abcdef\s]+$') but remove the current expression and allow it to look for spaces, tabs, carriage returns, and line feeds.

Comment: I ended up trying this and it worked fine:

re.compile(r'^[\t\r\n\s]+$')

Comment: You could use only `\s` (which means whitespace). A Whitescape can be a: **space**, **tab**, **carriage return**, **new line**, **vertical tab** or a **form feed** character.

Comment: so, in your example `r'^[\t\r\n\s]+$'` these commands `\t\r\n` are redundant, because we already have a `\a`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def check (pattern, allowed):
    return not set(pattern) - set(allowed)
```